# SQL Server 2008 R2: Split string into single column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to split given string into a single column.

**Example**:

Given String:

```
'A,B,C,D,E,F'
```

Expected Result:

```
ColumnA
--------
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns may help

Comment: This might help you.. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/798671/Split-string-into-Rows-Columns-using-Delimiters

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL: Opposite to string concatenation - how to split string into multiple records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `custom split() function`

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split(@String nvarchar(4000), @Delimiter char(1))
RETURNS @Results TABLE (colA nvarchar(4000))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @INDEX INT
DECLARE @SLICE nvarchar(4000)

SELECT @INDEX = 1
WHILE @INDEX !=0
BEGIN

SELECT @INDEX = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@STRING)
IF @INDEX !=0

SELECT @SLICE = LEFT(@STRING,@INDEX - 1)
ELSE
SELECT @SLICE = @STRING

INSERT INTO @Results(colA) VALUES(@SLICE)

SELECT @STRING = RIGHT(@STRING,LEN(@STRING) - @INDEX)

IF LEN(@STRING) = 0 BREAK
END
RETURN
END
```

Then run the query like below.

```
SELECT colA FROM [dbo].[Split] ('A,B,C,D,E,F', ',')
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cde98e/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @commavalue varchar(50)='A,B,C,D,E,F'
select q2.value from
(SELECT cast('<x>'+replace(@commavalue,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as Data)q1 CROSS APPLY
(SELECT x.value('.','varchar(100)') as value FROM Data.nodes('x') as f(x))q2
```